# Multiple fields within an id - Webdriver - Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The input fields I am needing to grab are within this `@id="contractorsWrapper"`.

In this example, there are 2 input fields within that wrapper (but this number is dynamic depending on the case) located at `@class="contactEntry"`.

What I'm trying to do is say, how many `className=contactEntry` fields are there within the `id=contractorsWrapper`. Then, be able to input text into them independently.

```
<div id="contractorsWrapper" class="contactInputAndInfoDisplays_wrapper">
  <div id="contractorsRow_5d1532ba-b37e-4aac-85c2-4a5e6c6c2796" class="contactInputAndInfoDisplay">
    <div class="contactName">
      <div class="contactFlag"/>
      <a class="smallRemove removeAContact" href="#"/>
      <span class="littleGreyTitles">
        Name
        <br/>
      </span>
      <input class="contactEntry " type="text" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="descriptionInput littleGreyTitles">
      Description
      <br/>
      <input type="text"/>
    </div>
    <a class="contactLink" href="#" style="display: none;"/>
  </div>
  <div class="spacerDiv1"/>
  <div id="contractorsRow_5fc58f1a-906f-4239-93ae-b0a2e4b8b70c" class="contactInputAndInfoDisplay">
    <div class="contactName">
      <div class="contactFlag"/>
      <a class="smallRemove removeAContact" href="#"/>
      <span class="littleGreyTitles">
        Name
        <br/>
      </span>
      <input class="contactEntry " type="text" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="descriptionInput littleGreyTitles">
      Description
      <br/>
      <input type="text"/>
    </div>
    <a class="contactLink" href="#" style="display: none;"/>
  </div>
  <div class="spacerDiv1"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find your wrapper:

```
WebElement wrapperElement = driver.findElement(By.id("contractorsWrapper"));
```

Number of input elements:

```
wrapperElement.findElements(By.className("contactEntry ")).size();
```

I don't know what you mean with "input text into them independently" but here's how you could enter the same thing in all of them:

```
for (WebElement element : wrapperElement.findElements(By.className(className))) {
            element.sendKeys("keysToSend");
};
```

#### update

after more details from OP

If you want to insert some "unique" Strings to the element, you can use an ArrayList

```
// create as much array entries as you need

List<String> namesList = new ArrayList<String>();
namesList.add("John Doe");
namesList.add("Jane Doe");
...
```

// then

```
int count = 0;
for (WebElement element : wrapperElement.findElements(By.className(className))) {
            element.sendKeys(namesList.get(count++));
};
```

of course you would then need to make sure, that your list is always longer than the number of input elements...

Comment: What I mean by "input text independently" is be able to enter John Doe in the first field and then Jane Doe in the second field, etc... depending on how many fields are returned.

I tried implementing what you suggested, but it's just failing at the for loop with "unknown error: cannot focus element".

Comment: regarding the "cannot focus element" -> are you using chromedriver? if yes try firefox (look here: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2023/webdriver-api-failed-to-send-keys-because-cannot-focus-element-better-work)

Comment: Yes, I was using chromedriver. I switched to Firefox and now it's entering the text. Thanks for the heads up on the chromedriver bug and for getting me this far.

So is there any way to isolate each entry field and use them separately? Maybe by getting the id's that start with "contractorsRow" and then accessing the child class contactEntry associated to that id? Is that feasible?

Comment: sure this would be possible, but what exactly do you wanna do then, you would need a mapping or something, which text should go into which input element? You should probably update your question with more details was what you are trying to accomplish - you could write some pseudo-code as for what you eventually wanna do

Comment: You rock my man! What you appended to your answer works great!